# Insightly Zapier

Tags: cognito-forms

I recently upgraded to Cognito Forms paid plan so that I could use Zapier to get stuff done. Cognito Forms has been great for the office as its layout is simple and the form generated looks great BUT every time I try to setup Zapier to pull the information from the form it will only show me information for Bob Smith.

Who is Bob Smith and why is he the only person who hasn't filled out a form get to be the only option I have in Zapier as an option?

I would like to be able to press the fetch button in Zapier and have the people on my list imported.

Any idea on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that "Bob Smith" is a sample data "feature" that allows you to build Zaps without having to submit an actual form. You just continue to build your Zap with Bob's info and then when you want to run it against your data, just run the Zap for real (instead of "fetch" in the building phase).

Also, I don't think you need to upgrade to a paid plan to use Zaps or other integrations.  Very generous of Cognito.

Caveat: I'm a new Cognito user as of yesterday.

BTW, if you have complex forms (repeating sections), I suggest checking out Microsoft LogicApps.  It handles them gracefully without having to write Zapier javascript code.